# How to change Windows Phone application bar icon color?

Tags: windows-phone-8, colors, icons, application-bar

How to handle application bar button click to prevent coloring this in theme color?

I have Windows phone 8 app with my own background and foreground colors, but when I'm clicking on app bar button (such as settings), it's coloring in red/green/blue/anything else theme color. It's crashing my design and I'm crying.

Other topics on stackoverflow have answers that it is impossible, but Skype on Windows Phone has white icon color on mouse (or finger, I would say) down event despite my color theme is emerald!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is impossible with the standard appbar. Your own to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to set `ForegroundColor` of `ApplicationBarIconButton`?

ps. It's generally bad idea to find something that available only in Microsoft apps, because they have access to the special or hidden API's which is not available to the regular developers.

Comment: Yes, it's not what I'm looking for.